# Cannot pass std::vector<bool> to winrt::array_view

Tags: c++, uwp, c++17, c++-winrt

I trying to consume [Windows::Gaming::Input::RawGameController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.rawgamecontroller) via [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) library.

Calling `RawGameController::GetCurrentReading()` to acquire current controller state:

```cpp
std::vector<bool> buttonsArray(rawController.ButtonCount(), false);
std::vector<GameControllerSwitchPosition> switchesArray(rawController.SwitchCount(), GameControllerSwitchPosition::Center);
std::vector<double> axisArray(rawController.AxisCount(), 0.0);
uint64_t timestamp = rawController.GetCurrentReading(buttonsArray, switchesArray, axisArray);
```

And have compile error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cppwinrtgamepad, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>cppwinrtgamepad.cpp
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(3458): error C2039: 'data': is not a member of 'std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool,
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(3663): note: see declaration of 'std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool,
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
1>c:\somepath\cppwinrtgamepad.cpp(121): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'winrt::array_view<T>::array_view<T>(std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>> &) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool,
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
1>c:\somepath\cppwinrtgamepad.cpp(121): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'winrt::array_view<T>::array_view<T>(std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>> &) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool,
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
1>c:\somepath\cppwinrtgamepad.cpp(90): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::fast_iterator<winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<winrt::Windows::Gaming::Input::Gamepad>>' being compiled
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(7801): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IContextCallback>' being compiled
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(7573): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IServerSecurity>' being compiled
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(7532): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::time_point<winrt::clock,winrt::Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan>' being compiled
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(5264): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IMarshal>' being compiled
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(2503): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<To>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            To=winrt::impl::ILanguageExceptionErrorInfo2
1>        ]
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(4120): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<To> winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IRestrictedErrorInfo>::try_as<winrt::impl::ILanguageExceptionErrorInfo2>(void) noexcept const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            To=winrt::impl::ILanguageExceptionErrorInfo2
1>        ]
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(4202): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IRestrictedErrorInfo>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\string_view(39): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_string_view<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>' being compiled
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(3458): error C2664: 'winrt::array_view<T>::array_view(winrt::array_view<T> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'winrt::array_view<T>::size_type' to 'std::initializer_list<bool>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>c:\somepath\x64\debug\generated files\winrt\base.h(3459): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>Done building project "cppwinrtgamepad.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

`GetCurrentReading()` is defined in `winrt/Windows.Gaming.Input.h` like this:

```cpp
template <typename D> uint64_t consume_Windows_Gaming_Input_IRawGameController<D>::GetCurrentReading(array_view<bool> buttonArray, array_view<Windows::Gaming::Input::GameControllerSwitchPosition> switchArray, array_view<double> axisArray) const
```

And corresponding `winrt::array_view` constructor is defined in `winrt/base.h` like this:

```cpp
template <typename C>
array_view(std::vector<C>& value) noexcept :
    array_view(value.data(), static_cast<size_type>(value.size()))
{}
```

Looks like oblivious bug considering that [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) doesn't contrain `data()` method at all.
Or there is other recommended way to call `RawGameController::GetCurrentReading()`?

PS: as a workaround I could use `std::array<bool, SOME_BIG_BUTTTON_COUNT>` but its so ugly.

Comment: What would the `data()` on a `std::vector<bool>` return?

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is a can of worms best avoided, because it's space-optimised (one bit per value) and thus doesn't behave anywhere similar to other `std::vector` instantiations. If you can, use `std::vector<char>` instead.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis issue is in C++/WinRT library that providing `winrt::array_view` wrapper around `std::vector` and `std::array`.
Specifically it have `RawGameController::GetCurrentReading()` with `array_view<bool>` in first parameter.

Comment: @Angew I cannot use `std::vector<char>` because `winrt::array_view<bool>` doesn't contain such constructor.

Comment: @fdan Button count is not fixed, I should call [`RawGameController.ButtonCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.rawgamecontroller.buttoncount) to properly know array size...I already mentioned it in PS.

Comment: @DJm00n I saw your note afterwards, sorry. Isn't `com_array` in the same header exactly what you need? from looking at the source, you could initialize `com_array` with your `vector` and it will perform a component-wise copy to it's internal structure` (which hopefully is no bitset but stores real bools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly workaround instead of using `vector<bool>`:

```cpp
int32_t buttons = rawController.ButtonCount();
int32_t switches = rawController.SwitchCount();
int32_t axis = rawController.AxisCount();

std::unique_ptr<bool[]> buttonsArray = std::make_unique<bool[]>(buttons);
std::vector<GameControllerSwitchPosition> switchesArray(switches);
std::vector<double> axisArray(axis);

uint64_t timestamp = rawController.GetCurrentReading(winrt::array_view<bool>(buttonsArray.get(), buttonsArray.get() + buttons), switchesArray, axisArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. The `winrt::array_view` is an adapter that tells the underlying API that the bound array or storage has the appropriate binary layout to receive the data efficiently (typically via a `memcpy`) without some kind of transformation. `std::vector<bool>` does not provide that guarantee and thus cannot be used. You might want to try something else like a `std::array` or some other contiguous container.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that `std::vector<bool>` is not really a container at all.

Comment: Which array size should I use for `std::array<bool, SIZE>`?

Comment: That depends on how many you wish to receive. It's just allocating a buffer that the API will then write data to.

Comment: @kenny-kerr could you add std::unique_ptr<T> constructor to `array_view`?

Something like:
```cpp
template <typename C>
array_view(std::unique_ptr<C[]> const& value, size_type size) noexcept :
 array_view(value.get(), size)
{}
```

so I could use it like:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<bool[]> buttonsArray = std::make_unique<bool[]>(buttons);
uint64_t timestamp = rawController.GetCurrentReading({ buttonsArray, buttons }, switchesArray, axisArray);

```
?

Comment: You can always create a custom buffer and pass a pair of begin/end pointers/iterators.

Comment: Yes, but `{ buttonsArray, buttonsCount }` is far more better for my eye than `winrt::array_view<bool>(buttonsArray.get(), buttonsArray.get() + buttonsCount)`.

Comment: What does the `binary layout` mean?

Comment: The caller and callee must agree on the binary layout (ABI) in order to communicate information correctly. In other words, how the values are packed into memory and transferred across the ABI boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Each element in `std::vector<bool>` occupies a single bit instead of sizeof(bool) bytes.It does not necessarily store its elements as a contiguous array and thus doesn't contain `data()` method.I have a working code, but it is not the optimal solution.You can try to create bool array by using bool b[] method.

```
bool buttonsArray[]{ rawController.ButtonCount(), false };
std::vector<GameControllerSwitchPosition> switchesArray(rawController.SwitchCount(), GameControllerSwitchPosition::Center);
std::vector<double> axisArray(rawController.AxisCount(), 0.0);
uint64_t timestamp = rawController.GetCurrentReading(buttonsArray, switchesArray, axisArray);
```